# How to return function constructor itself?

Tags: javascript

I have a function constructor, for example,

```
let 

    app = function(){
       return new app();
    };
```

I want to return the constructor itself but as expected it makes an error of maximum call stack. There is a simple way to do that like this below,

```
let 

    app = function(){
        return app.fn(); // or app.fn.init() anything like that (what jQuery does)
    }
```

I don't know what is the best or good way to do that. So again my destination is that I want to return the constructor itself as simple as possible? It should be the same when I call `app()` as `new app()`.

Another question is that "Is it good or bad to use this method"?

Comment: when you just want to return the constructor, wouldn't you have to return `app` and not `new app()`? Like that you're returning an instance

Comment: it should be a ```new app()```

Comment: but when you do `new App()` this returns an instance anyway...

Comment: actually I need an object of this constructor nothing else in any way.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you mean you want an instance when `app` is called, even if it's not called via `new`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes. I just forgot to write it sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want an instance when `app` is called, even if it's not called via `new`, you'd do this in ES2015+:

```
let App = function() {
    if (new.target) {
        // Called as part of an instance creation operation, just return `this`
        return this;
    }
    // Not called during instance creation, create an instance and return it
    return new App();
};
```

Or with older ES5 syntax, you'd probably use `instanceof`:

```
var App = function() {
    if (this instanceof App) { // Is `this` an instance created by `App`?
        // Yes, just return it
        return this;
    }
    // No, create an instance and return it
    return new App();
};
```

**But**, I prefer requiring that the function be called in a consistent way (either with `new` or not with `new`, but consistently). You can get a built-in check that the function was called as part of a instance creation operation by using `class` syntax, since it disallows calling a constructor via [[Call]] instead of [[Construct]].

Answer (score 1):

You want a function that instantiates a class?

```
// This is the class and constructor
const App = function() {
  // This is a property
  this.created = new Date()

  // This is a method
  this.age = function() {
    return new Date() - this.created
  }
}

// This creates the instance
const makeApp = function() {
  return new App()
}
```